# How to connect mongodb database in python on a server ubuntu?

Tags: python, mongodb, ubuntu, server, ubuntu-server

I have the IP address of my apache server, running on ubuntu 18.04. I have installed MongoDB on the server. I have a script in python to connect the database but it doesn't work. I have shh connection without authentication for the database

I have already tried SSHTunnelForwarder but unsuccessfully.

```py
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
from pymongo import MongoClient

MONGO_HOST = 'MY_IP_ADDRESS'

server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    MONGO_HOST,
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 27017)
)

server.start()

client = MongoClient('127.0.0.1', server.local_bind_port)
db=client.myDatabaseName
```

I have also tried

```py
client = MongoClient('mongodb://MY_IP_ADDRESS/')
```

Comment: Hi! I didn't understand the ssh tunnel part. Your mongo instance is running locally or in a remote  server?

Comment: The mongo instance is in a remote server. The ssh tunnel part was a test that I find on the internet.